# Definition query that returns based on date in arcgis

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, query, date

I was wondering if anyone knew how to build a definition query in Arcmap 10.0  that returns only features that are f.e. only 7 days old.
I have a SDE geodatabase with polygons, each with a "date"-field (format yyy-mm-dd). I would like to select these features based on their age:

> Output 1 ;  Last 7 days
>
> Output 2 ;  Last 14 days
>
> Output 3 ;  Last 30 days
>
> Output 4 ;  Last year
>
> ....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by: `Feature 3 ; Last 30 days`

Comment: There is an [**ArcGIS Discussion Forum**](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/29503-Help-with-Definition-Query-for-Current-Date-minus-7-days) thread that may help. Also, can you use the edit button to revise your Question to include the RDBMS flavour and version that you are accessing via ArcSDE, please?

Comment: Sorry i meant different output options

Comment: Is your "date" field recognized as a date type? What SQL queries have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on an SDE/Oracle database - select the dates within the last year you can do something like this:

```
ACQUIREDATE > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)
```

or last 7 days

```
ACQUIREDATE > SYSDATE - 7
```

Comment: This worked great for me.  (ArcGIS SDE 10.2, Oracle 11g)